# Showing a DIV while hovering another DIV in a loop

Tags: php, html, css, hover

i am trying to show a div when hovering another div. I researched this forum for solutions but i did not find anything that matched my problem, because mine is in a loop from 0 to 9. I know i just missed something really basic, i just cannot find it.

The whole code is PHP, the HTML lines are made with 'echo'.
I want .runestext$i to show up when .runes$i is hovered. 
So, for example,  when .runes1 is hovered i want to show up .runestext1 ^^
Here is my code:

```
<?php>
for ($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++) {

//FROM HERE

if ($i >= 5) {
    $top_position = 493;
}
else {
    $top_position = 133;
}

if ($i >= 5) {
    $r = 18 + 250 * $i - 250 * 5 - 612.5;
}
else {
    $r = 18 + 250 * $i - 612.5;
}

$runes = getRunes($summoner_currentgame_specified);


echo "<style> " . ".runes" . $i . "{" . 
       "position: absolute;
        left: " . $r . "px;" . 
       "top: " . $top_position . "px;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #fff;
        font-family: Verdana, Friz Quadrata Thin, sans-serif;
        font-weight:bold;" . 
     "</style>";

echo "<div id='a' class=runes" . $i . ">Runes</div>";

echo "<style> " . ".runes" . $i . ":hover" . "{" .
       "position: absolute;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
        width: 225px;
        height: 300px;
        margin-left: -21px;
        margin-top: -273px;
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid #fff;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 25px;" . "}" .
     "</style>";

//TO HERE ALL IS WORKING FINE, just for clarity of the code

echo "<style>" . ".runestext" . $i . "{
        font-family: Verdana;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: none; }" . 
      "</style>";

echo "<div id='b' class=runestext" . $i . ">RUNESTEXT</div>";

//Here my mistake should be, i just cannot find it:    
echo "<style>" . ".runes" . $i . ":hover .runestext" . $i . "{" .
       "display: block;" . "}" . 
     "</style>";
}
</php>
```

I really hope you guys can help me as i dont get this working after a lot of time of trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears your `runestext` is not a child of `runes`, which means you need the sibling selector `~` to target it.

```
// ------------------------------------- ↓
echo "<style>" . ".runes" . $i . ":hover ~ .runestext" . $i . "{" .
       "display: block;" . "}" . 
     "</style>";
}
```

*Side notes*

1. You also miss a rule closure `}` in this style

   ```
   echo "<style> " . ".runes" . $i . "{" . 
         "position: absolute;
           left: " . $r . "px;" . 
         "top: " . $top_position . "px;
          font-size: 16px;
          color: #fff;
          font-family: Verdana, Friz Quadrata Thin, sans-serif;
          font-weight:bold;" . 
        "</style>";
   ```
2. Don't use the same id on your div's, it should be unique